# Ap Gateway + Lambda : how to enable compression

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on an API Gateway (REST API) with some Lambda function behind it, set up using SAM.

Even when enabling the gzip/conflate compression (by setting the *MinimumCompressionSize* on my SAM template or directly in the API Gateway console), nothing is happening. The endpoints still return a non-compressed answer, with no encoding header (even when the request contains an accept-encoding: 'gzip, deflate, br' header).

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, the problem seems to come from the fact that the Gateway/Lambda integration is done in the AWS_PROXY mode, meaning that the Gateway act as a pure proxy and does not modify the request or response coming to/from the Lambda.

As such it won't be able to compress the response (as this would require modifying the content and the headers).

A workaround is to set up a CloudFront distribution in front of the Gateway, with the "Compress: true" property. CloudFront will serve as a cache in front of the Gateway and provide on-flight compression when the client requires it.